# Домашняя страница на Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Добрый день уважаемому сообществу.

Недавно читал статью, вроде бы на хабре, о движке для GAE, специально предназначенному для создания домашних страниц для программистов. Если мне не изменяет память, были возможности для интеграции сайта с различными сервисами, вроде GitHub и BitBucket.

К сожалению, я сейчас не могу найти ни статью, ни домашнею страницу этого движка.
Может кто-то с ним сталкивался, или может посоветовать нечто подобное?

Comment: tps://developers.google.com/appengine/?hl=ru

Comment: Я имел виду уже готовый движок, не вижу смысла писать ещё один велосипед.

Comment: Используй любую CMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чудом нашёл движок - [Syte](https://github.com/rigoneri/syte).

Правда, по умолчанию, он не предназначен для работы с GAE, но и не использует базу данных и часть логики основывается на JavaScript, так что не будет проблем с портированием .